# End of script output before headers: multiplicar.cgi

Tags: html, perl

He estado haciendo un ejemplo sencillo de una calculadora utilizando html y perl con el módulo CGI pero no entiendo el error aquí esta el formulario en HTML

```
<form id="formu" action="multiplicar.cgi" method="POST" class="form register">
  <h2 class="form_titulo"> Calculadora </h2>  
     <div class="contenedor-inputs">
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="numero"  id="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa el número  " maxlength="2" class="input-100" required    />   
       <input type="text" name="numero2"  id="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa el número  " maxlength="2" class="input-100" required    />   
<input type="radio" name="opcion" value="sumar" /> Suma <br /> 
<input type="radio" name="opcion" value="restar" />Resta<br /> 
<input type="radio" name="opcion" value="multiplicar" />Multiplicación<br /> 
<input type="radio" name="opcion" value="dividir" />Division<br /> `
</td> 
   <input class="form-btn" type="submit" id="btnenviar" value="Ingresar"/>



     </div>

  </form>
```

Y el código en perl con el módulo CGI es el siguiente:

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"

use strict;
use CGI;

my $cgi  = new CGI;
my $num  = $cgi->param('numero');
my $num2 = $cgi->param('numero2');
my $op   = $cgi->param('opcion');

if ($op eq "sumar") {
    $total = $num+$num2;
}
elsif ($op eq "restar") {
    $total = $num-$num2;
}
elsif ($op eq "multiplicar") {
    $total = $num*$num2;
}
elsif ($op eq "dividir") {
    if ($num2 <= 0) {
        $total = "No se puede dividir entre 0";
    }
    else {
        $total = $num/$num2;
    }
}
else {
    $total = "opción inválida";
}

print $cgi->header("text/html");
print $total;
```

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje de error dice que el servidor web está recibiendo texto sin haber recibido antes las cabeceras obligatorias.

En el programa vemos la llamada a header() correctamente puesta, así que el problema debe estar en otro sitio. Quizás, es que Perl está sacando algún mensaje de error.

Si pasamos el programa con la opción **-c** Perl hará una comprobación sintáctica:

```
perl -c multiplicar.cgi
```

Si no sale, nada, es que todo está bien, pero en este caso, sale esto:

```
Global symbol "$total" requires explicit package name at calculadora.pl line 12.
Global symbol "$total" requires explicit package name at calculadora.pl line 15.
Global symbol "$total" requires explicit package name at calculadora.pl line 18.
Global symbol "$total" requires explicit package name at calculadora.pl line 22.
Global symbol "$total" requires explicit package name at calculadora.pl line 25.
Global symbol "$total" requires explicit package name at calculadora.pl line 29.
Global symbol "$total" requires explicit package name at calculadora.pl line 33.
```

El módulo **strict** nos obliga a programar de forma estricta, así que Perl se quejará si usamos una variable si antes no la hemos declarado, que es justo lo que está pasando: no está declarada la variable **$total**.

La solución es poner esto al principio del programa:

```
my $total;
```

Comment: como puedo hacer lo que me dijistes de perl -c no lo comprendí bien

Comment: ya entendi ... solamente como que no me detecta la opción es raro

Comment: Si al ejecutar el cgi desde la línea de comandos con la opción -c, no sale ningún mensaje, es que Perl no ha detectado ningún problema sintáctico, así que en principio, el programa está bien.